# Getting a NullPointerException when trying a pom in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Trying to create and Selenium POM framework from scratch .
Class 1 :consist of login, class 2 consist of ur ,class- executing everything .
i am not extended any file
Getting exception at css method not sure how to rectify

```
    Class 1 :
    public class LOGIN {
    
    WebDriver driver;
        public LOGIN(WebDriver driver){
            
            this.driver = driver;
        }
        
        public void facebook(){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Balu\\Desktop\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
            driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        }
    
    }    
    
    Class 2 : 
    public class Home  {
        
        WebDriver driver;
    
        public Home(WebDriver driver){
            this.driver = driver;
                }
        
    public void css(){  
 
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
        
    
    }
       
    
    Class 3 :
    public class Test1 {
        
        private static final WebDriver driver = null;
    
        @Test
        public void e2eflow(){
            LOGIN lg = new LOGIN(driver);
            Home hm = new Home(driver);
            lg.facebook();
            hm.css();
            
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: `private static final WebDriver driver = null;` You didn't initialize the `driver`

Comment: But chrome is getting launched ,facebook url is opened

Comment: Yes, because you initialized it in other class but `Test1` doesn't have access to the initialized `driver`

Comment: I didnt get you ,sorry

Comment: `driver` variable is initialized in `LOGIN` class. `Test1` class has no access to it. It has it's own variable called `driver` but it's not initialized. It's `null`

Comment: ok got it but how to resolve it

Comment: You need to read about Object-Oriented Programming. Try to find solutions for `DriverFactory`. If you want to understand why doesn't it work - you need to acquire more knowledge and then, you can ask specific questions.

Simply fixing this issue will lead to another one. So far you can try to use one of the answers provided in the question

Comment: thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

```
class LOGIN {

public static WebDriver driver;
    public LOGIN(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
    }
    
    public void facebook(){           
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    }

}
```

```
class Home extends LOGIN {
    
public void css(){  

 driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
 }
```

```
class Test1 {
    
    @Test
    public void e2eflow(){
       
       Home hm = new Home();
       hm.facebook();
        hm.css();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: An error occurred while instantiating class Practise_Constructor.Test1: null

Answer (score 0):

`driver` is null in `Test1`, that's why you're getting the exception

Answer (score 0):

driver = new ChromeDriver() instead of null.

Comment: Syntax error on token "driver", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token , getting this error while entering driver = new chrome

Answer (score 0):

In your test classes you are declaring the driver as null.
As you want to use POM pattern, I suggest go trough this tutorial: [POM tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html)

You can have a method marked with @BeforeTest where you are setting up your driver, or you can do it in a class and extend it in all test classes.